# How can I find windows of a specific application and place them into a grid?

Tags: bash, scripts, window-manager, wmctrl

I'm trying to write a script to identify all open chrome windows and move them into a grid layout on a large screen

I'm not sure how to find out what the best resolutions would be so I was going to manually add them in to a array so if 1 chrome window was available then maximise that, if 2 chrome windows available then go to a array for sizes for that?

At the moment I can move every window on the screen (does break my display when doing this) but I can see to work out how to move just the chrome screens?

The script below are some ideas I had but please point in the correct direction as at the moment the script doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
#Chrome window crontroller 


# Monitor 1920 X 1800

# Choose array for number of screens available 

# Different screen positions 
G=0
win1_X=5;      win1_Y=24;    win1_W=639;   win1_H=499;
win2_X=642;    win2_Y=24;    win2_W=639;   win2_H=499;
win3_X=1280;   win3_Y=24;    win3_W=639;   win3_H=499;
win4_X=5;      win4_Y=552;   win4_W=639;   win4_H=499;

ChromesAvailable()
{
    CA=$(wmctrl -lx | grep Chromium | wc -l)
}


GetNumOfChrome()
{
  WID=$(wmctrl -l | grep n | awk '{print$1}')
  #echo "INFO: window id = $WID"
}


PlaceWindow()
{
  X=${n}_X; Y=${n}_Y; W=${n}_W; H=${n}_H; 
  wmctrl -i -r "$WID" -e $G,${!X},${!Y},${!W},${!H}
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
 case "$1" in

        *)
            echo "ERROR: invalid option $1"
            echo "see --help for usage"
            exit 1
            ;;
  esac
  exit 0
else
for n in win{1..4}; do
    GetNumOfChrome
    PlaceWindow
done

fi
```

Edited - To explain things better :-)

Using `grep n` will load every open window on the system so I tried to use `grep Chromimum` but the script doesn't like this

```
 GetNumOfChrome()
    {
      WID=$(wmctrl -l | grep n | awk '{print$1}')
      #echo "INFO: window id = $WID"
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain exactly how the script fails. "Does not work" is not very informative :). Also, why are you running `wmctrl -l | grep n`? Was that supposed to be `grep -n`?

Comment: So, what is the `grep -n` supposed to do? That will print any lines containing the letter `n`, how is that relevant?

Comment: The `n` should feed into the PlaceWindow function that gets it's the details for the window sizing from the top. I'm happy to go down a different route if you think that is better

Comment: So what is your main goal ? Open bunch of windows and set it to different size  and see which one works better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach is to arrange the windows form a pre- defined(customizable) grid (columns/rows)

An example:

[image]

rearranged into (`cols` set to 3, `rows` set to 2):

[image]

rearranged into (`cols` set to 4, `rows` set to 2):

[image]

The script below can be used to do that. As said, the number of columns&rows can be set, as well as the padding between the windows. The script calculates then the positions the windows should be arranged into, as well as their sizes.

#### Using the wmctrl command on Unity

The `wmctrl` command shows some peculiarities when used to move windows to- or very nearby the launcher or the panel. Therefore the margins:

```
left_margin = 70; top_margin = 30
```

cannot be set to zero. You have to keep at least a few px distance to both the panel and the launcher. I'd suggest leaving both margins- values as they are. All other values, padding, columns and rows you can play around with and set it as you like.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import sys

#--- set your preferences below: columns, rows, padding between windows, margin(s)
cols = 2; rows = 2; padding = 10; left_margin = 70; top_margin = 30
#---

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
def get_res():
    xr = get("xrandr").split(); pos = xr.index("current")
    return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

# get resolution
res = get_res()
# define (calculate) the area to divide
area_h = res[0] - left_margin; area_v = res[1] - top_margin
# create a list of calculated coordinates
x_coords = [int(left_margin+area_h/cols*n) for n in range(cols)]
y_coords = [int(top_margin+area_v/rows*n) for n in range(rows)]
coords = sum([[(cx, cy) for cx in x_coords] for cy in y_coords], [])
# calculate the corresponding window size, given the padding, margins, columns and rows
w_size = [str(int(area_h/cols - padding)), str(int(area_v/rows - padding))]
# find windows of the application, identified by their pid
pids = [p.split()[0] for p in get("ps -e").splitlines() if sys.argv[1] in p]
w_list = sum([[w.split()[0] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if p in w] for p in pids], [])
print(pids, w_list, coords)
# remove possibly maximization, move the windows
for n, w in enumerate(w_list):
    data = (",").join([str(item) for item in coords[n]])+","+(",").join(w_size)
    cmd1 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_horz"
    cmd2 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_vert"
    cmd3 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -e 0,"+data
    for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

#### How to use

1. Make sure `wmctrl` is installed :)
2. Copy thye script into an empty file, save it as `rearrange_windows.py`
3. In the head section of the script, set your preferences
4. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rearrange_windows.py <application>
   ```

   example: to rearrange `chromium` windows:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rearrange_windows.py chromium
   ```

   to rearrange `chrome` windows

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rearrange_windows.py chrome
   ```

#### Note

The script can be used to put windows of any application into a grid, since the *process name* of the application is used as an argument.

---

### EDIT

#### Dynamic version

below a dynamic version of the script, as requested in a comment. This version of the script calculates the number of columns and rows, depending on the number of windows. The proportions of the rearranged window(s) is similar to the proportions of the screen.

The setup and the use is pretty much the same as the version above, only the number of columns and rows is now set automatically.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import sys
import math

#--- set your preferences below: padding between windows, margin(s)
padding = 10; left_margin = 70; top_margin = 30
#---

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
def get_res():
    xr = get("xrandr").split(); pos = xr.index("current")
    return [int(xr[pos+1]), int(xr[pos+3].replace(",", "") )]

# find windows of the application, identified by their pid
pids = [p.split()[0] for p in get("ps -e").splitlines() if sys.argv[1] in p]
w_list = sum([[w.split()[0] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if p in w] for p in pids], [])
# calculate the columns/rows, depending on the number of windows
cols = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(w_list))); rows = cols
# define (calculate) the area to divide
res = get_res()
area_h = res[0] - left_margin; area_v = res[1] - top_margin
# create a list of calculated coordinates
x_coords = [int(left_margin+area_h/cols*n) for n in range(cols)]
y_coords = [int(top_margin+area_v/rows*n) for n in range(rows)]
coords = sum([[(cx, cy) for cx in x_coords] for cy in y_coords], [])
# calculate the corresponding window size, given the padding, margins, columns and rows
if cols != 0:
    w_size = [str(int(area_h/cols - padding)), str(int(area_v/rows - padding))]
# remove possibly maximization, move the windows
for n, w in enumerate(w_list):
    data = (",").join([str(item) for item in coords[n]])+","+(",").join(w_size)
    cmd1 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_horz"
    cmd2 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -b remove,maximized_vert"
    cmd3 = "wmctrl -ir "+w+" -e 0,"+data
    for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
        subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])
```

See below the examples with a varying number of opened windows:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

#### Explanation (second script)

*Finding the specific windows*

1. The command:

   ```
   wmctrl -lp
   ```

   lists all windows, in the format:

   ```
   0x19c00085  0 14838  jacob-System-Product-Name *Niet-opgeslagen document 1 - gedit
   ```

   where the first column is the window's unique id, and the third column is the pid of the application that owns the window.
2. The command:

   ```
   ps -e
   ```

   lists all processes, in the format:

   ```
   14838 ?        00:00:02 gedit
   ```

   where the first column is the application's pid, the last one is the process name.
3. By comparing these two lists, we can find all windows (id of-) which belong to a specific application (called `w_list` in the script, as the result of line 17/18 in the script):

   ```
   pids = [p.split()[0] for p in get("ps -e").splitlines() if sys.argv[1] in p]
   w_list = sum([[w.split()[0] for w in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines() if p in w] for p in pids], [])
   ```

*Calculating the number of rows/columns*

1. If we make the windows of the same proportions as the screen, that means the number of columns is equal to the number of rows.
2. That implies that both the number of colums and rows are equal to the rounded up square root of the number of windows to rearrange. That is done in line 20:

   ```
   cols = math.ceil(math.sqrt(len(w_list))); rows = cols
   ```

*Calculating the window size and position*

1. Once we have the number of columns, all we need to do is divide the available area (screen resolution - left margin/top margin) in the columns/rows and we have the *targeted window size*, which is then diminished by the `padding`, as set in the head of the script:

   ```
   w_size = [str(int(area_h/cols - padding)), str(int(area_v/rows - padding))]
   ```
2. The *horizontal (x) positions* are the result of the product(s) of the *horizontal window size* (including padding) times the column number, in a range of the number of columns. for example: if I have 3 colums of 300 px, the resulting x-positions are:

   ```
   [0, 300, 600]
   ```
3. The *vertical (y) positions* are calculated likewise. Both lists are then combined into a list of coordinates, in which the windows will be rearranged.

   This is done in line 26-28 of the script:

   ```
   x_coords = [int(left_margin+area_h/cols*n) for n in range(cols)]
   y_coords = [int(top_margin+area_v/rows*n) for n in range(rows)]
   coords = sum([[(cx, cy) for cx in x_coords] for cy in y_coords], [])
   ```
4. The actual rearranging finally (after unmaximizing possibly maximized windows) is done from line 33 and further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer when I run the script nothing happens, i've checked that I've got the correct bits installed

Comment: @Grimlockz That is odd, I just rechecked the script. Could you add a line: `print(pids, w_list, coords)`  after:  `w_list = sum([[w.split()[0]....` (after line 26) and see what it sais when run from the terminal?

Comment: sure `['3051'] [] [(70, 30), (452, 30), (835, 30), (1217, 30), (70, 320), (452, 320), (835, 320), (1217, 320), (70, 610), (452, 610), (835, 610), (1217, 610)]
`

Comment: @Grimlockz in your question, you mention `chrome`, but from the comment on terdon's answer (and looking into your script) I understand you mean `chromium`, which has a different process nam. I changed the script to rearrange windows of any application, with the process name as an argument. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks , that seems to work fine for 2 windows but when tried on 6 windows I get this ` python3 chrome3.py chromium 
['3042', '3052', '3058', '3081', '3104', '3150', '3217', '4509', '7660', '7784', '7813', '7832', '7856', '7940', '8050'] ['0x03e00001', '0x03e00054', '0x03e000d8', '0x03e000d9', '0x03e000da', '0x03e000db'] [(70, 30), (835, 30), (70, 465), (835, 465)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chrome3.py", line 31, in <module>
    data = (",").join([str(item) for item in coords[n]])+","+(",").join(w_size)
IndexError: list index out of range
`

Comment: @Grimlockz That means that your windows (6 as it seems) do not fit in a grid of four (2x2). so you need to increase the number of columns/rows, as set in `cols = 2; rows = 2` in the head section of your script. You need at least:  `cols = 3; rows = 2` for six windows. The script can easily be made to put outnumbering windows *on top* of existing windows however, starting in the same positions again.

Comment: Ahhh Thats silly of me...woops - How would you make it dynamic so to fit all chromium windows into a gred depending on how many are active

Comment: @Grimlockz posted an additional "dynamic" version.

Comment: Your dynamic version throws an ` IndexError: list index out of range` error on my system, complaining about line 17 `pids = [p.split()[0] for p in get("ps -e").splitlines() if sys.argv[1] in p]`. Same thing happens with 0,1,2,3 or 4 open windows.

Comment: @terdon I dare not ask, but did you use the application's process name as an argument :) ? That is about the only IndeError that can occur, since `p.split()[0]` only appears if `p.split()[0]` appears in the output of `ps -e`, and there simply *must* be a first column then in the line.  `sys.argv[1]` however will of course occur if the argument (processname) is missing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm repeat after me: "users are idiots, users are idiots, users are idiots". No I hadn't :) Now it does tile the windows but not all of them. With three windows, it will tile 2 correctly and the third is maximized. With 4, one takes the right size, one takes half the screen and the other two are maximized. With two, both take more or less the right size but are placed at the top right of my screen, one over the other.

Comment: @terdon would you do me the favour to run the script, but with an additional line `print(cmd3)` after `cmd3 = ` (line 36). I'd like to see if there is an error in the script (wrong command), or that `wmctrl` chokes somehow in a timing issue.

Comment: Sure, but let's [move this to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23802/tiling-windows).

Answer (score 3):

The script below will tile an arbitrary number of chrome or chromium windows in a Nx2 grid (N rows, 2 columns) where N depends on the number of open windows. If there is only one window, that window will be maximized (or unmaximized if it is already maximized).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#################################################
# Exit if there are no running chrome processes #
#################################################
pgrep "chrom[e|ium]" &>/dev/null || 
    echo "No Chrom[e|ium] processes are running" 1>&2 && exit
#########################
# Get screen dimensions #
#########################
read width x height < <(xrandr | grep -Po 'current\s*\K.*?(?=,)' )

###################################################################
# Get the names of all Chrome windows. I am using PIDs because    #
# searching by name will match anything with chrome/chromium in   #
# the title, not only chromium windows. It also matches a firefox #
# window open on this AU question, for example.                   #
###################################################################
mapfile -t windows < 
    <(wmctrl -pl | grep -f <(pgrep "chrom[e|ium]") | 
                   cut -d' ' -f1)

####################################
# Get the number of Chrome windows #
####################################
numofwins=${#windows[@]}

#########################################
# Initialize the x and y positions to 0 #
#########################################
x=0
y=0

#############################################
# Get 1/2 the number of windows, rounded up #
#############################################
halfwins=$(printf "%.f" "$(echo $numofwins/2 | bc -l | 
                           awk '{print int($1+0.5)}')")

######################################################
# If there's only one window, maximize/unmaximize it #
######################################################
[[ $numofwins -eq 1 ]] && 
    wmctrl -i -r "${windows[@]}" -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz &&  
    exit;

##########################################################################
# The height of each window will be the height of the display divided by #
# half the number of windows                                             #
##########################################################################
winheight=$(printf "%.f" "$(echo $height/$halfwins | bc -l)")

##################################################################
# The width of each window will be half the width of the display #
##################################################################
winwidth=$(($width/2))

##################################
# Iterate over each window found #
##################################
for winID in "${windows[@]}"
do
    ########################################
    # Increment a counter. This is used to #
    # know when we should change rows.     #
    ########################################
    let c++
    ###############################
    # Position the current window #
    ###############################
    wmctrl -i -r "$winID" -e 0,$x,$y,$winwidth,$winheight
    ##################################################
    # If the counter is a multiple of 2, change rows #
    ##################################################
    if [[ $((c % 2)) -eq 0 ]]
    then
        y=$((y+$winheight+2))
        x=0
    #######################################
    # If it isn't, move to the right only #
    #######################################
    else
        x=$((x+$winwidth+2))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Again, a good answer more. +1 :)

Comment: @terdon thanks for all the work on this, I'm excited to use the script but when I run it I just get a list of `3042
3051
3052
3058
3081
3104
3150
3217
4509
4808
` and no window move, I have 2 chrome windows open and another 3  other programs open as well

Comment: Also I've done a process grep and with only 2 chrome window opens I get this `ps -ef | grep "chrom[e|ium] | awk '{print $8}' 
chromium-browser
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox
chromium-browser
chromium-browser
chromium-browser
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro
chromium-browser
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chro`

Comment: @Grimlockz that output should no longer be printed. The `ps` will return all sorts of things, yes, but I'm using the `ps` output to `grep` through the output of `wmctrl` so only processes listed by both should be shown. I don't know why it fails on your system, it works on mine but I don't use unity. That might be an issue. Does uity work with `wmctrl`? Try pinging me in the Ubuntu [chat] room and we can debug it.

Comment: I think using it on Unity *is* an issue, since it does not work on my system as well. `wmctrl` does work on Unity, but at least one issue is that the `wmctrl` resize/move command does not work as expected without at least a few px from both launcher and panel.

Comment: @JacobVlijm yeah, I used a tiny offset of 2 pixels. I can't test properly on my system because i) I have tint2 running which takes up some screen real estate and ii) I use cinnamon whose panel is a little wonky. It does place windows in a grid though. Does it just do nothing on your system or are the windows placed wrongly?